# How can I get the top 10 odd numbers in an array using LINQ in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I need a query to find out the top 10 odd numbers in an array using LINQ in C#.

I tried the below code. It works, but I need a single LINQ query to find the top 10 records.

```
int[] Arr1 = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 1, 12, 11, 34, 221, 33, 13, 55,
               123, 44, 222, 232, 45, 656, 67, 56, 445, 456 };

var result = from y in Arr1 where y%2 == 1 select y;
int c = 1;
foreach (var item in result)
{
    if (c <= 10)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
        c++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Arr1.Where(x => x%2 == 1).Take(10)` will return the first 10 odd numbers (or less if there are not 10).  I'm not sure if that's what you mean by "top 10"

Comment: int[] result = Arr1.Where(x => x % 2 == 1).Take(10).ToArray();

Comment: Wery unclear why the question is looking for answers using EF (based on "entity-framework-core" tag) as code use inline array for the data and not some sort  of data coming from a DB... For regular LINQ we already have plenty of simile "get top" posts and one is selected as duplicate. Feel free to [edit] the post to clarify if it is indeed some new problem that needs to be answered in this question.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you have a LINQ query already in `var result = from y in Arr1 where y%2 == 1 select y;` ... so you could just write that as

```
var result = (from y in Arr1 where y % 2 == 1 select y).Take(10);
```

But personally I have found that style of LINQ to be hard to read and maintain (and not as flexible, since in a case like this we end up having to use the "method" style anyway).

So I would encode your condition using `Where`.

```
var result = Arr1.Where(n => n % 2 == 1);
```

Then take only the first 10 elements that match that condition.

```
var result = Arr1.Where(...).Take(10);
```

Then your `foreach` loop doesn't need a counter variable as result is an enumerable with 10 or fewer elements in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the numbers that are odd and then order the list descendingly which means the largest will be at the top of the list and then take the first ten elements from the list with the code below:

```
int[] Arr1 = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 1, 12, 11, 34, 221, 33, 13, 55, 
               123, 44, 222, 232, 45, 656, 67, 56, 445, 456 };

// Get the odd numbers
var largestOddNumbers = Arr1.Where(n => n % 2 != 0)

// Sort from the largest to the smallest
.OrderByDescending(n => n)
    .Take(10); // Take only the first ten elements
```